# Change pip from 3.4 to 3.5

Tags: raspbian, python, pip

Recently, I have installed python3.5 on raspi, while I had 3.4 (by default). So now I have a problem with pip, because it is linked with 3.4 and not 3.5, so whenever I install package, it is done for 3.4 and not 3.5. I have no clue how to fix it. This is what I tried:

```
pip -V
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
pip3 -V
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)
```

Anything like pip-3.4/5 does not work

From: https://docs.python.org/3.5/installing/index.html

```
python3.5 -m pip install <package_name>
/usr/local/bin/python3.5: No module named pip
```

But same approach works for python2.7 and 3.4.

Last attempted was with:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

Got an error:

```
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1558k  100 1558k    0     0  1880k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1879k
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pip
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
```